# Word meaning something obvious

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word meaning "something very obvious". I thought of the word "obviosity", as in "I can't believe that I have to explain such obviosities to you" but apparently it's not a real word.

Are there any real words that I can use to mean the same thing as "obviosity"?

Comment: Can you tell us the result of looking up the word in your native language in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

There is the term "axiom", which is "a statement that is self-evident" It tends to be used in mathematical contexts: such as "for any two points, there is just one line which passes through both of them" is an axiom of geometry.

But this doesn't fit your context. In the given context I would allow context to fill the meaning.

> Of course you have to wear pants.  I can't believe I have to explain such things to you.

In the context "things" refers to "the thing which I can't believe I have to explain" and so must refer to "obvious things".  You can give the meaning without spelling it out.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an English noun with that meaning, but a noun phrase like any of the following are natural: "I can't believe I have to explain **something so basic/obvious/trivial/self-evident** to you."

(In fact, I'm saddened to learn "obviosity" isn't a real word. Ten minutes ago I would have said it was.)